# CTE Paging, with Count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pagination, common-table-expression

I have a sproc that I'm running that I'm trying to use pagination but also return back the entire product count.  It's "working" but the problem is that when I take out the totalCount CTE and remove it from the final SELECT my sproc runs in ~50ms. When I keep it in there my query takes 7-8 seconds.  It's a large query if I grab all records but the idea is to grab just the page I need but I need to return total records.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

/****  MAIN SEARCH BLOCK  ****/

```
WITH search_results AS
(

SELECT DISTINCT     
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @sortExpression) as rowNumber,
            products.pid,
            brands.bid,
            brands.brand_name,
            products.model,
            products.name,
            products.searchedprice
            products.status

FROM products WITH (NOLOCK)
            JOIN brands WITH (NOLOCK) ON products.bid=brands.bid

WHERE   
    (
           CONTAINS(products.*,@inflectionSearchText)
           OR
           CONTAINS(brands.Brand_Name,@inflectionSearchText)
    )
    AND
      products.productstatus=1
    AND 
      brands.brandstatus=1
    AND
      products.searchedprice BETWEEN @fromprice TO @toprice

),
totalCount AS 
(SELECT COUNT(*) Total FROM search_results)

SELECT * 
FROM search_results, totalCount
WHERE 
     rowNumber BETWEEN ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize)+1 
         AND ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize)+@pageSize

ORDER BY products.model
```

Comment: a DISTINCT with row_number() and no grouping? why?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan, particularly for that last `JOIN` between `search_results` and `totalCount`? Would returning the total count in an `OUTPUT` parameter suffice? Would it be close to `Max( rowNumber )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach to retrieve the count without performing a sub-select.

```
SELECT some_field, COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
FROM some_table
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9669/1)